# Automatic locale detection in Next.js 13 on Amplify Compute Hosting not working

Tags: reactjs, next.js, internationalization, aws-amplify

[Amplify support for Next.js SSR](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/ssr-Amplify-support.html) points to automatic locale detection, but I was not able to implement it.

`next.config.js` has a localeDetection option that automatically redirects users to their preferred language, but the feature does not work on Amplify.

It seems to rely on Accept-Language header, which seems to be blocked by Amplify (It's unclear to me).

On introduce amplify for next.js, I'm not sure why automatic locale detection is added if this header is blocked.

Middleware and Next.js internal redirect with `localeDetection` cannot read Accept-Language headers.

```
//next.config.js

i18n: {
    locales: ["en", "sv"],
    defaultLocale: "en",
    localeDetection: true
}
```

Comment: Can you update with the version of Next.js that you're using. Also, if the app has any customizations in the build settings, etc.

Comment: Using Next.js 13.2.1, no customizations in the build phase

Comment: It does not work because it's listet under the `Unsupported features` section on the page you linked.